# switch to root to execute commands through Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, sudo

Hi I start a python script by using `python script.py`.

But I need to write into a file which is inside the `/usr/local/etc` folder that requires permission of `root`. So I think I need to spawn a child process with `sudo`; the password to run the `as sudo` must be hardcoded into the script.

How do I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574201/running-python-script-as-root

Comment: You can configure sudo so it does not require a password. You can also require the python script be started by root (that is, by "sudo script.py) and then use the os.setresuid call to change privileges for the necessary parts of the program.