# Why does SetSUID not work for shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create a executor program for regular users on linux with SUID bit set so whatever commands, passed to the program as parameters, get executed with root permission. However when I try to implement this as a bash script, this does not work, where it works when implemented in C. I want to know what I am doing wrong for the shell script. The codes are below

Shell Script:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
echo "Usage: $0 <Command String>"
exit 1
fi
$@
#Also tried this, same result
#exec $@
```

Execution:

```
root#: chmod 755 exec.sh 
root#: chmod u+s exec.sh
root#: ll exec.sh
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 75 Sep 19 16:55 exec.sh

regular_user$: ./exec.sh whoami
regular_user
```

C Program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
if ( argc < 2 ) {
    printf( "Usage: %s <Command String>\n", argv[0] );
    return 1;
}
else
{
    argv[argc]=NULL;
    //setuid(0);  //Works without these
    //setgid(0);
    int exit=execvp(argv[1], argv+1);
    return exit;
}
}
```

Execution:

```
root#: gcc exec.c -o exec.obj
root#: chmod 755 exec.obj
root#: chmod u+s exec.obj
root#: ll exec.obj
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 6979 Sep 19 17:03 exec.obj

regular_user$: ./exec.obj whoami
root
```

Both files have identical permissions

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 75 Sep 19 16:55 exec.sh
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 6979 Sep 19 17:03 exec.obj
```

Comment: What's wrong with sudo? ;)

Comment: The approach is wrong, you should configure `sudo` or use `super`

Comment: Actually we have lots of linux servers with ldap auth and ldap sudo group, but this particular one runs an oracle database and we need to keep it locked down, so I need a trivial hack to let DBAs run  commands as root sometimes.

Comment: You could have a special `/etc/sudoers` on that machine, or install `super` and ask your DBA to use it.

Comment: I've decided to use sudo with local sudoers file and I also got the answer of why it wasn't asking. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Do not change title to show the problem is solved - accepting the answer makes it

Comment: possible duplicate of [SUID not working with shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698976/suid-not-working-with-shell-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is documented in [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) :

> Linux ignores the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits on scripts.

<sup>IIRC, setuid scripts would be a significant security hole</sup>

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18698976/841108)

You could configure `sudo` to avoid asking a password - see [sudoers(5)](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_sudoers.htm) (or use `super`)

You could also write a simple C program wrapping your shell script, and make it setuid.

Comment: Workaround: Use `sudo`

Comment: I have decided to use sudo as it permits finer grained control, however I just wanted to know why suid approach was not working. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
regular_user$: sudo "./exec.sh whoami"
```

Comment: Please explain more details about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is explain by **RedHat** at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/124693 :

> When executing shell scripts that have the setuid bit (e.g., perms of rwsr-xr-x), the scripts run as the user that executes them, not as the user that owns them. This is contrary to how setuid is handled for binaries (e.g., /usr/bin/passwd), which run as the user that owns them, regardless of which user executes them.

In order to solve this issue I write a script utility which converts a script call to a native binary:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/124693

if [ $# != 1 ]; then
    echo "Please, provide script file name." >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ ${EUID} != 0 ]; then
    echo "Only root can run this script." >&2
    exit 1
fi

SCRIPT_FILE=$1

if [ ! -f "${SCRIPT_FILE}" ]; then
    echo "Script file not found." >&2
    exit 1
fi

SCRIPT_BASE_FILE=$(basename ${SCRIPT_FILE})

C_TEMPLATE=$(cat << DELIMITER
#include <libgen.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char *cwd;
    char exe_file[PATH_MAX];
    char script_file[PATH_MAX];

    readlink("/proc/self/exe", exe_file, PATH_MAX);
    cwd = dirname(exe_file);
    sprintf(script_file, "%s/${SCRIPT_BASE_FILE}", cwd);

    setuid(0);
    system(script_file);
    return 0;
}
DELIMITER
)

C_FILE="${SCRIPT_FILE}.c"
EXE_FILE="${SCRIPT_FILE}.x"

   echo "${C_TEMPLATE}" > "${C_FILE}" \
&& gcc "${C_FILE}" -o "${EXE_FILE}" \
&& chown root:root "${EXE_FILE}" \
&& chmod 4755 "${EXE_FILE}" \
&& rm "${C_FILE}" \
&& echo "Setuid script executable created as \"${EXE_FILE}\"."
```