# How do I delete a file owned by root from within bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to delete a file (/var/lib/pacman/db.lck) owned by root user from within a simple script owned by a non-privileged user:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f /var/lib/pacman/db.lck
```

But I don't want to run the script using `sudo` in order to avoid typing password each time I execute the script as a non-privileged user. In order to achieve this I set the `s` bit:

```
-rwsrwsrwx  1 popov  users       41 04.02.2015 10:35 unlock.sh
```

But after running the script I get

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/pacman/db.lck’: Permission denied
```

It seems that I wrongly understand the purpose of `s` bit.

So the question is: How to setup the script permissions (and/or perhaps ownership of the script) which will let the script to delete a root-owned file when invoked by a non-privileged user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SUID not working with shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698976/suid-not-working-with-shell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is replacing the shell script with a little C program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILENAME "/var/tmp/dummy"

int main() {
    if(unlink(FILENAME) == -1) {
        printf("unlink() of %s failed: %s\n", FILENAME, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Change the `FILENAME`
- Save it as `unlink_it.c`.
- Compile using `gcc -Wall -o unlink_it unlink_it.c`
- Copy it to a suitable place (perhaps `/usr/local/bin`).
- Change the owner to root
- Add the SUID bit to the program
- Call the special purpose program from your unprivileged shell script.

*Beware:* Any user on the system can launch the program and thus delete the file unless you limit its use using the UNIX permissions!

Comment: A nice step-by-step tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: This is a really insecure solution.

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. It makes sure that only this particular file will be deleted. As I mentioned, you need to limit the users that are allowed to run this program using UNIX permissions.

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is that sudo asks the password, you could configure sudo with "NOPASSWD" option with this command. Something like that:

```
joe ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/command
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted answer, because this answers the real question, and the other one is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the script needs to be owned by the user that is given to the script while executing (in your case, `root`). However, SUID shell scripts are a bad idea (see comment).

The proper solution is not to run the script as SUID, instead you should give the user write permission to the *directory* that the file resides in. Then the script can unlink (delete) the file even if it belongs to another user and it has no permission to write to it.

A concrete example: You have a user "popov" that is member of the group "popov" and a directory /var/lib/pacman

```
chgrp popov /var/lib/pacman
chmod g+w /var/lib/pacman
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would rather not change group of a sensitive system folder which uses important system utility pacman (package manager). It may produce more problems (and eventual security holes) than benefits.