# how to run a shell script as different user without promting password

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a shell script moveInvoice.sh with chmod 777 permission as user test1 and all other scripts are under user test2.

Now I need to call  moveInvoice.sh from test2 I tried following

```
sudo -c 
sudo -u
```

But all are giving permission denied. Is there any other way to make it run with test2 user ?

once manually I am able to execute then I need to put this in crontab

Comment: Try with linux acl

Comment: I cannot use acl bcos it needs utilities to be installed. Since it is office network we dont have any root access to install such. So any command line  commands will be helpful.

Comment: Write a binary wrapper for the script that can `setuid()` [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24919588/4162356) an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a user on Linux to be able to run sudo without a password by adding a `NOPASSWD` option in visudo.

run `sudo visudo` as root and then add your user under privilege specification as `SOMEUSER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`.

now, `SOMEUSER` will be able to run sudo commands without a password.